# Gradle custom task for jar

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am using Gradle for my Java project and I was wondering if it's possible to prevent `gradle build` from creating a jar file each time executed.

Also, is it possible to have a custom task for creating the Jar with dependencies at a specific location `build/myAppJar/`.

Here's what I have so far for the custom task:

```
task toJar (type: Jar) {
    from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'myApp',
                'Implementation-Version': 1.0,
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

The above code will create the jar file under `build/libs`, and the file does not contain the compiled files, only the dependencies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `build` task comes from the `java` plugin. You can control when a jar is built with something like this:

```
jar {
  onlyIf { condition }
}
```

You can set jar to be built when you declare something else to be true, or hard set it to false to never build a jar.

You can include sourcesets in your `toJar` custom task, to include compiled files into your jar.

```
task toJar (type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.all
}
```

You are explicitly calling for all compile time dependencies to be included in the jar here: `from configurations.compile.collect`

ref: [Gradle java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: That works, thank you, I just changed`sourceSets.all` to `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`